# Joining multiple iteratorars by a key

Tags: python

Given: n iterators, and a function to get a key for an item for each of them

Assuming:

- The iterators provide the items sorted by the key
- The keys from any iterator are unique

I want to iterate through them joined by the keys. Eg, given the following 2 lists:

```
[('a', {type:'x', mtime:Datetime()}), ('b', {type='y', mtime:Datetime()})]
[('b', Datetime()), ('c', Datetime())]
```

Using the first item in each tuple as the key, I want to get:

```
(('a', {type:'x', mtime:Datetime()}), None)
(('b', {type:'y', mtime:Datetime()}), ('b', Datetime()),)
(None, ('c', Datetime()),)
```

So I hacked up this method:

```
def iter_join(*iterables_and_key_funcs):
    iterables_len = len(iterables_and_key_funcs)

    keys_funcs = tuple(key_func for iterable, key_func in iterables_and_key_funcs)
    iters = tuple(iterable.__iter__() for iterable, key_func in iterables_and_key_funcs)

    current_values = [None] * iterables_len
    current_keys= [None] * iterables_len
    iters_stoped = [False] * iterables_len

    def get_nexts(iters_needing_fetch):
        for i, fetch in enumerate(iters_needing_fetch):
            if fetch and not iters_stoped[i]:
                try:
                    current_values[i] = iters[i].next()
                    current_keys[i] = keys_funcs[i](current_values[i])
                except StopIteration:
                    iters_stoped[i] = True
                    current_values[i] = None
                    current_keys[i] = None

    get_nexts([True] * iterables_len)

    while not all(iters_stoped):
        min_key = min(key
                      for key, iter_stoped in zip(current_keys, iters_stoped)
                      if not iter_stoped)

        keys_equal_to_min = tuple(key == min_key for key in current_keys)
        yield tuple(value if key_eq_min else None
                    for key_eq_min, value in zip(keys_equal_to_min, current_values))

        get_nexts(keys_equal_to_min)
```

and test it:

```
key_is_value = lambda v: v
a = (  2, 3, 4,  )
b = (1,          )
c = (          5,)
d = (1,   3,   5,)
l = list(iter_join(
        (a, key_is_value),
        (b, key_is_value),
        (c, key_is_value),
        (d, key_is_value),
    ))
import pprint; pprint.pprint(l)
```

which outputs:

```
[(None, 1, None, 1),
 (2, None, None, None),
 (3, None, None, 3),
 (4, None, None, None),
 (None, None, 5, 5)]
```

Is there an existing method to do this? I checkout itertools, but could not find anything.

Are there any ways to improve my method? Make it simpler, faster, etc..

### Update: Solution used

I decided to simplify the contract for this function by requiring the iterators to yield tuple(key, value) or tuple(key, *values). Using agf's answer as a starting point, I came up with this :

```
def join_items(*iterables):

    iters = tuple(iter(iterable) for iterable in iterables)
    current_items = [next(itr, None) for itr in iters]

    while True:
        try:
            key = min(item[0] for item in current_items if item != None)
        except ValueError:
            break

        yield tuple(item if item != None and item[0]==key else None
                    for item in current_items)

        for i, (item, itr) in enumerate(zip(current_items, iters)):
            if item != None and item[0] == key:
                current_items[i] = next(itr, None)


a = (      (2,), (3,), (4,),      )
b = ((1,),                        )
c = (                        (5,),)
d = ((1,),       (3,),       (5,),)
e = (                             )

import pprint; pprint.pprint(list(join_items(a, b, c, d, e)))

[(None, (1,), None, (1,), None),
 ((2,), None, None, None, None),
 ((3,), None, None, (3,), None),
 ((4,), None, None, None, None),
 (None, None, (5,), (5,), None)]
```

Comment: are `{...}` in the first 2 code blocks supposed to denote functions? I don't seen the relationship between the first code block, and the `None`s that show up in the 2nd one.

Comment: The {...} are to denote dictionaries containing arbitrary data.  I'll update the question to show this.

Comment: You got the syntax for dictionaries wrong in your example. It should read `[('a', {'type':'x', 'mtime':Datetime()})...`.

Comment: I win for the only answer without `dict`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = (  2, 3, 4,  )
b = (1,          )
c = (          5,)
d = (1,   3,   5,)

iters = [iter(x) for x in (a, b, c, d)]

this = [next(i) for i in iters]

while True:
    try:
        key = min(i for i in this if i != None)
    except ValueError:
        break
    for i, val in enumerate(this):
        if val == key:
            print val,
            this[i] = next(iters[i], None)
        else:
            print None,
    print
```

Comment: Ah - I did not know about the next function. Reading the documentation, I see that you could do next(iter, None), which should mean you don't need to use repeat.

Comment: @GaryvanderMerwe Quite true. I actually use that all the time but just wasn't thinking about it as I was in a rush when I wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

The example at the beginning of your question is different than at the end.

For the first example, I would do this:

```
x = [('a', {}), ('b', {})]
y = [('b', {}), ('c', {})]
xd, yd = dict(x), dict(y)
combined = []
for k in sorted(set(xd.keys()+yd.keys())):
    row = []
    for d in (xd, yd):
        row.append((k, d[k]) if k in d else None)
    combined.append(tuple(row))

for row in combined:
    print row
```

gives

```
(('a', {}), None)
(('b', {}), ('b', {}))
(None, ('c', {}))
```

For the second example

```
a = (  2, 3, 4,  )
b = (1,          )
c = (          5,)
d = (1,   3,   5,)

abcd = map(set, [a,b,c,d])
values = sorted(set(a+b+c+d))
print [tuple(v if v in row else None for row in abcd) for v in values]
```

gives

```
[(None, 1, None, 1),
 (2, None, None, None),
 (3, None, None, 3),
 (4, None, None, None),
 (None, None, 5, 5)]
```

But what are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps you need different data structures.

Comment: Yes I could put the data in to dicts. I was trying to avoid that because the datasets will be quite large, and I receive some of the datasets sorted, so I want to try take advantage of that.

Comment: Nice. Golfed: `dicts = [dict(iterable) for iterable in iterables];
combined = [tuple((k, d[k]) if k in d else None for d in dicts) for k in sorted(set(dicts[0]).union(*dicts[1:]))]`

Comment: Yes, data structures, and key functions are different. For my actual use, the datasets are in different formats. I'm was hoping for a method that is flexible to handle. Maybe I could simplify it by requiring that the iterators yield tuple(key, value), and wrap the actual iterators with a iterator that does this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools as it
import heapq
import pprint

def imerge(*iterables):
    '''
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/491285-iterator-merge/
    Author: Raymond Hettinger

    Merge multiple sorted inputs into a single sorted output.

    Equivalent to:  sorted(itertools.chain(*iterables))

    >>> list(imerge([1,3,5,7], [0,2,4,8], [5,10,15,20], [], [25]))
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 15, 20, 25]

    '''
    heappop, siftup, _StopIteration = heapq.heappop, heapq._siftup, StopIteration

    h = []
    h_append = h.append
    for it in map(iter, iterables):
        try:
            next = it.next
            h_append([next(), next])
        except _StopIteration:
            pass
    heapq.heapify(h)

    while 1:
        try:
            while 1:
                v, next = s = h[0]      # raises IndexError when h is empty
                yield v
                s[0] = next()           # raises StopIteration when exhausted
                siftup(h, 0)            # restore heap condition
        except _StopIteration:
            heappop(h)                  # remove empty iterator
        except IndexError:
            return

a = (  2, 3, 4,  )
b = (1,          )
c = (          5,)
d = (1,   3,   5,)

def tag(iterator,val):
    for elt in iterator:
        yield elt,val

def expand(group):
    dct=dict((tag,val)for val,tag in group)
    result=[dct.get(tag,None) for tag in range(4)]
    return result

pprint.pprint(
    [ expand(group)
     for key,group in it.groupby(
          imerge(*it.imap(tag,(a,b,c,d),it.count())),
          key=lambda x:x[0]
          )])
```

Explanation:

- Life would be easier if we mergesort the iterators. This can be done
  with `imerge`
- `itertools.groupby` gives us the desired grouping if we feed it the
  result from `imerge`. The rest is just niggling details.

  ```
  pprint.pprint(
     [ list(group)
      for key,group in it.groupby(
           imerge(a,b,c,d))
       ] )
  # [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5, 5]]
  ```
- From the output above, it is clear we need to keep track of the
  source of each value -- (did the value come from `a`, or `b`, etc.).
  That way we can pad the output with `None`s in the right places.
- To do that I used `it.imap(tag,(a,b,c,d),it.count())`. `tag(a)`
  returns an iterator which yields values from `a` along with a counter
  value.

  ```
  >>> list(tag(a,0))
  # [(2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0)]
  ```
- The output now looks like this:

  ```
  pprint.pprint(
     [ list(group)
      for key,group in it.groupby(
           imerge(*it.imap(tag,(a,b,c,d),it.count())),
           key=lambda x:x[0]
           )])

  # [[(1, 1), (1, 3)], [(2, 0)], [(3, 0), (3, 3)], [(4, 0)], [(5, 2), (5, 3)]]
  ```
- Finally, we use `expand(group)` to change `[(1, 1), (1, 3)]` into
  `[None, 1, None, 1]`.

Comment: Interesting solution. Made my think about the problem in a very different way.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the answer has already been decided. However I do think that a cleaner way can be written up using the defaultdict object from the collections library.

Here is an example from http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/collections.html

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...    d[k].append(v)
>>>>d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Comment: That loads the whole dataset in to a dict which I want to avoid because the datasets will be very large. Also, this dose not track which iterator the value came from.