# Stretch columns to pair matched cells in rows

Tags: python, gnumeric

Example table:

```
  A  |  B  |  C  | ...
-----+-----+-----+----
  3  |  2  |  2  |    
  5  |  3  |  4  |    
  7  |  4  |  6  |    
  9  |  5  |  8  |
```

I would like somehow to temper it with Gnumeric and produce matching cells across columns:

```
  A  |  B  |  C  | ...
-----+-----+-----+----
  -  |  2  |  2  |    
  3  |  3  |  -  |    
  -  |  4  |  4  |    
  5  |  5  |  -  |    
  -  |  -  |  6  |    
  7  |  -  |  -  |    
  -  |  -  |  8  |    
  9  |  -  |  -  |
```

Real example if with string values instead numbers but it is easier to explain with numbers I think

If this is not trivial and someone has idea how this can be done with Python lists instead table columns in Gnumeric please post a Python solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to do in Python:

```
a = [3, 5, 7, 9]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [2, 4, 6, 8]

a_ex, b_ex, c_ex = zip(*(
                        [elem if elem in col else None
                            for col in a, b, c] 
                                for elem in set(a).union(b, c)
                      ))
```

Seems the most direct if you're not worried about the speed.

I also just noticed my answer to [Joining multiple iteratorars by a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689205/joining-multiple-iteratorars-by-a-key/7690207#7690207) sort of applies:

```
def paditers(*args):
    iters = [iter(x) for x in args]

    this = [next(i) for i in iters]

    while True:
        try:
            key = min(i for i in this if i != None)
        except ValueError:
            break
        for i, val in enumerate(this):
            if val == key:
                yield val
                this[i] = next(iters[i], None)
            else:
                yield None

padded = list(paditers(a, b, c))
next_item = iter(padded).next
print zip(*((next_item(), next_item(), next_item()) 
         for _ in range(len(padded) // 3)))
```

You can adapt that if you need performance to scale linearly.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that Python (or any familiar language) is the way to go. Thanks! Let's see how will take for some larger lists ;)

Comment: I posted a very slightly modified version of my answer to another question which scales linearly instead of quadratically. It assumes sorted values, but the same idea could be adapted if you're looking for just matches.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it if I notice issues, but just to say on sample test with 5 columns and ~ 1000 string elements in each, your one-liner finished in glimpse, like if I typed `2 + 2`. Impressive Python